# Removing every line from a large text file except specific lines

Tags: linux, bash, optimization

For my project I am handling large data files, when these data files come in they are "uncleaned" and I need to clean them so that I can calculate the required functions from them. In this data the first 9 line is text and information about for example the time, and number of atoms. Whilst the next 10000 lines it is trajectory data this repeats until a certain time.

Now I have written code that cleans the text out of it given by:

```
homedir=$(pwd) #print working directory

for ex in 0 #5

do
dirname="ex-$ex"
cd $dirname

    dirname2="Tq-0.25-N10000" 
        cd $dirname2

       for i in $(seq 1 1 100)  
       do
       dirname3="tr-$i"
           cd $dirname3
          
       
        mv traj-passive-afterquench.atom traj-afterquench
        sed -i "1,9d" traj-afterquench
        awk '{if((NR-1) % 10009<=9999){print $0}}' traj-afterquench>test
           

              cd .. # tr
       done
cd .. # Ti-1
cd .. # ex 
done
```

But now I want to create another file that removes every line except the time, these are located on the lines of 2+10009*i where i is the number of timesteps till the end of the file, how would I create a code that would remove every line except the ones in the given formula?

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU `sed`:

```
sed '2~10009!d' file
```

should do the job.

Comment: Ah okay perfect, I should have that, would the original file be altered in this case or?

Comment: @TimvanSchaik No, it wouldn't. You can redirect the output to another file: `sed '2~10009!d' file > newfile`, or use `-i` option to edit _in place_.